# Why is my Orchard driver returning multiple content shapes?

Tags: orchardcms

I want to build shapes for only "Parts_McrfProfile_List" and, for whatever reason, the "Parts_McrfProfile_Summary" keeps getting hit instead.  Can anyone lead me into the right direction as to why this keeps happening?

Here is the code for my driver:

```
    protected override DriverResult Display(
        McrfProfilePart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        return Combined(
       ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile",
                         () =>
                         {
                             part.ProfileDetail = _profileService.GetProfileDetail(part.ProfileId);

                             McrfProfileDetailViewModel profileDetailViewModel = new McrfProfileDetailViewModel();

                             profileDetailViewModel.ProfileDetail = part.ProfileDetail;

                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile(ProfileDetail: profileDetailViewModel);
                         }),
        ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_List",
                         () =>
                         {
                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile_List(ProfileRecord: part);
                         }),
        ContentShape("Parts_McrfProfile_Summary",
                         () =>
                         {
                             McrfProfileSummaryViewModel profileSummaryViewModel = new McrfProfileSummaryViewModel();

                             List<int> profileID = new List<int>() { part.ProfileId };

                             var summary = _profileService.GetProfileSummaryList(profileID).Where(e => e.ProfileID == part.ProfileId).First();

                             profileSummaryViewModel.JobTitle = summary.JobTitle;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.Name = summary.Name;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileImage = summary.ProfileImage;
                             profileSummaryViewModel.ProfileID = summary.ProfileID;

                             return shapeHelper.Parts_McrfProfile_Summary(ProfileRecord: profileSummaryViewModel);
                         }));

    }
```

Here is the code of the call:

```
foreach (var contentItem in contentItems.ContentItems)
{
                               list.Add(_mcrfContentManager.BuildDisplay(contentItem.Content, "Parts_McrfProfile_List"));
}
```

Comment: Maybe some error or missing entries in your placement.info ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your placement.info file in your module to control what shapes from your driver are displayed. In your BuildDisplay method the second parameter is the display type, not the shape you want to return. You really want something like this:

```
.BuildDisplay(contentItem.Content, "ListView")
```

Then in your Placement file:

```
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_McrfProfile="Content:1" />
</Match>
<Match DisplayType="ListView">
    <Place Parts_McrfProfile_List="Content:1" />
</Match>
<Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_McrfProfile_Summary="Content:1" />
</Match>
```